# KQL | How do I extract or check for data in a long string with many quotation marks?

Tags: extract, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm super newbie to KQL and data in general.

I'm working with a data column with long strings like this:

`"data": {"stageID":1670839857060,"entities":[{"entity":{"key":"BearKnight","owner":0,"id":"[2|1]"},"levels":{"main":4,"star":1,"ShieldWall.main":4,"ShieldWall.enhance":0,"ShieldThrow.main":4,"ShieldThrow.enhance":0}},{"entity":{"key":"DryadHealer","owner":0,"id":"[3|1]"},"levels":{"main":5,"star":1,"HealingTouch.main":5,"HealingTouch.enhance":0,"CuringTouch.main":5,"CuringTouch.enhance":0}},{"entity":{"key":"HumanKnight","owner":1,"id":"[4|1]"},"levels":{"main":4,"star":0,"BullRush.main":4,"BullRush.enhance":0,"FinishingStrike.main":4,"FinishingStrike.enhance":0,"SwordThrow.main":4,"SwordThrow.enhance":0,"StrongAttack.main":0,"StrongAttack.enhance":0}},`

I need to get a list of the *HeroNames *inside here [ "key":"*HeroName*","owner":**0** ] but not in here [ "key":"*HeroName*","owner":**1** ].

I've been trying the extract_all and has_any functions, but I can't work with the data if it has all the quotation marks. Can I parse this somewhow and remove them?

My ideal output would be a list of hero names who have owner:0.
For example, for the top string the ideal output is: "BearKnight","DryadHealer"

Comment: That seems like a broken JSON. If that is indeed the case, please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
print txt = 'data: {"stageID":1670839857060,"entities":[{"entity":{"key":"BearKnight","owner":0,"id":"[2|1]"},"levels":{"main":4,"star":1,"ShieldWall.main":4,"ShieldWall.enhance":0,"ShieldThrow.main":4,"ShieldThrow.enhance":0}},{"entity":{"key":"DryadHealer","owner":0,"id":"[3|1]"},"levels":{"main":5,"star":1,"HealingTouch.main":5,"HealingTouch.enhance":0,"CuringTouch.main":5,"CuringTouch.enhance":0}},{"entity":{"key":"HumanKnight","owner":1,"id":"[4|1]"},"levels":{"main":4,"star":0,"BullRush.main":4,"BullRush.enhance":0,"FinishingStrike.main":4,"FinishingStrike.enhance":0,"SwordThrow.main":4,"SwordThrow.enhance":0,"StrongAttack.main":0,"StrongAttack.enhance":0}}]}'
| parse txt with * ": " doc
| mv-apply e = parse_json(doc).entities on (where e.entity.owner == 0 | summarize HeroNames = make_list(e.entity.key))
| project-away txt, doc
```

| HeroNames |
| --- |
| ["BearKnight","DryadHealer"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WST0/CQBDF736KyV4AUwiogDbh4J8YjIkHIfFAiJm0E3Zlu0t2t9YK/e5uQaBAjKem771pf3kzCyOUA/flYAC1GB2GsGTW4YyeHljY6fXb15c3191%20u9cOGCknnCDLwsly85KzcMnm5B/sjtA8KzHjjgVMZ4oMC/2MiL03uVh1pqwImKRPkrYcSlAoFl4F5c98shOwERck4zeUsrUzKxopjiqi9Uc38pgbnR1nN%20I%20XBTBKeuDyTEeEkoPeQp7%20QdstwJbDgs1G%20s04q2dfaBWge9Tc5quiv8AD9ME1XG7nS3w1X/teoK7VMrX1PJ9XzulCvoolLDcY42cEXPap4%20Ng3Vk2pxsY68dRJ3RanbrHEbz3/CxWq1iWtTOVrBAY2l9pJlwHM6BhcAg1pH3ks8mLhYyB/IXvA6%20f1it6t5ttLYHC1pBPeNkCGgj5q11iTAYQBtWYNMkQSO%20CYZk9AsmfmYACc7pXQrr6rspv45Go0Qy%20oMi18QM85IsKHF%20APVJpJlNAwAA)